# Change filter in an explisit measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to change the filter of a explicit measure in order not having to re-create measure again. Calculation groups are not an options since that will effect the performance to much.

Let's take this scenario:

```
Gross Profit =
Calculate([Sales]-[Costs],
fact[scenario] = "Actuals"
)
```

Then, if I want to calculate the Gross Profit for the Budget scenario, is there anyway to reference the measure with actuals? I have LOTS of P&L measure, where I want to calculate the equivalent for the budget scenario.

First I tired something like this, but then realized that it doesn't impact the filter context of the explicit measured [Gross Profit]

```
Gross Profit Budget = 
Calculate([Gross Profit],
FILTER(ALL(fact[scenario]),
fact[scenario] = "Budget"
))
```

Any thoughts on how you can alter the filter of [Gross Profit] when refrencing it in another measure?

Comment: What you can do is add a reference table containing the two values `Budget` and `Actual`, and then you change your filter into `SELECTED(reference)`

Comment: No, I don't believe you can achieve what you want that way, since conditions past to `CALCULATE` always proceed from the outermost to the innermost, so, using your example, ultimately the condition `fact[scenario] = "Actuals"` will always prevail over any conditions applied to that column via additional, external `CALCULATE` calls.

Comment: Create a parameter and refer to it in the filter? "Budget" or "Actuals"

Comment: Interesting thought about the parameters, but I can't use an external filter where I would fetch the current value from parameter since moth measures will be in the same visuals. @Pieter, you see any way around that?